# How can I search for the embedded documents in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongo-shell

I have a collection like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbe1867839c0d2b4bdffcb2"),
    "name" : "Jyothish",
    "favBooks" : [
            {
                    "title" : "Let us C",
                    "author" : "Yaswanth Kanetkar",
                    "price" : 400
            },
            {
                    "title" : "Winner stands alone",
                    "author" : "Paulo Coelho",
                    "price" : 340
            }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bbe1b62839c0d2b4bdffcb3"),
    "name" : "John",
    "favBooks" : [
            {
                    "title" : "Broken Republic",
                    "author" : "Arundhathi Roy",
                    "price" : 200
            },
            {
                    "title" : "One Life to Ride",
                    "author" : "Ajit Harisinghani",
                    "price" : 250
            }
    ]
}
```

Is there any way to search for favBooks which have price less than 400?

What I am trying now is

```
db.p.find({"favBooks.price":{$lt:400}}).pretty()
```

But this will return all the documents has a favBook item with price less than 400.

What output I am expecting is

```
{
        {
                "title" : "Winner stands alone",
                "author" : "Paulo Coelho",
                "price" : 340
        },
        {
                "title" : "Broken Republic",
                "author" : "Arundhathi Roy",
                "price" : 200
        },
        {
                "title" : "One Life to Ride",
                "author" : "Ajit Harisinghani",
                "price" : 250
        }
}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation using [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$replaceRoot`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "favBooks.price": { "$lt": 400 }}},
  { "$unwind": "$favBooks" },
  { "$match": { "favBooks.price": { "$lt": 400 }}},
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": "$favBooks" }}
])
```